# create subprocess object from already running process

Tags: python, process, popen

I would like to create an `subprocess.Popen` object from an already running process... Is that possible somehow?

Another idea would be to serialize (pickle) the subprocess object and write it to a database so that if the main process restarts it could get the `subprocess.Popen` objects back from the database. I'm unsure if that works.

Comment: Based on your current wording, I don't believe a clear answer can be given. Could you describe what you're actually trying to accomplish in generic terms? E.g. Process A spawns backend Process B to....

Comment: If you restart the main process, the former child process is no longer a child process of the new main process.  At least on Linux, things like `wait()` won't work for processes which are not child processes of the current processes.  I'm not aware of a way of "adopting" orphaned processes.  Maybe your main process just should not die?

Answer (score 2):

> create an subprocess.Popen object from an already running process

Do you mean from an already running sub-process? The only way I know of to pass objects between processes is to pickle them and write them out either to a file or a database as you suggested.

Typically, sub-processes cannot be spawned from already running sub-processes, but you can keep a reference to the new process you want to create and spawn it from the main process. This could get really ugly, and I suggest against it strongly. Why, specifically do you need to further your process tree past two-deep? This info might lead to a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to communicate with the "subprocess" and must do so using its standard i/o streams, you could create a wrapper around the executable that maps its stdin/out/err to a socket or named pipe.

The program that intends to control the "subprocess" can then start and stop communications at any time. You may have to provide for a locking mechanism too.

Then, assuming you're on Linux, you can access the stdin/out/err of a running process through `/proc/<pid>/fd/<0,1,2>`. You won't connect these to a subprocess.Popen object but `open('/proc/<pid>/fd/1', 'rb')` will behave like `Popen().stdout`.